# A class with 6 Americans and 4 Canadians will be divided randomly in pairs. Chance of two American–Canadian pairs.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I am desperately stuck in this combination problem. 
Anybody can solve it? Thanks

> A class has 6 American students and 4 Canadian students. The class will be divided randomly in pairs for roommates. What's the chance that there will be two pairs of an American student and a Canadian student?

I've narrowed down the whole set as $(10)!/(5!2^5)$. I am stuck what to do after this, to find out the number of options for having two pairs of an American and a Canadian.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Everything. I don't know what the answer is so I'm asking what you guys think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the ten students in a line. The first student may be matched with any of $9$ other students, the second unmatched student may be matched with $7$ and so on. Thus the total number of pairings is $9×7×5×3×1=945$.

The number of pairings with exactly two bi-national pairs can be calculated as the product of the number of ways to:

- choose two Canadian and two American students ($\binom62\binom42=90$ ways)
- choose which American the first Canadian is matched to ($2$ ways)
- pair the remaining Canadians and Americans among themselves ($3$ ways for the Americans, $1$ for the Canadians)

The product works out to $540$. Thus the probability is $\frac{540}{945}=\frac47$.